# How to get an App for a very limited and known audience approved on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43536224/1612743), which recommends going through the App Store when targeting a small set of known users (the specific example is a set of contractors for a small company, but to avoid getting sidetracked by the Enterprise program, lets assume they are members of the local minigolf club):

What steps should I take to increase the likelihood of App Store approval in such a case. Is password based authorization and a clear description usually sufficient?

Specifically, I'm worried about this snippet from [the App Store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/):

> **Not enough lasting value**
>
> If your app doesn’t offer much functionality or content, or *only applies to a small niche market*, it may not be approved. Before creating your app, take a look at the apps in your category on the App Store and consider how you can provide an even better user experience.

Comment: If it's that targeted, perhaps distributing it as an enterprise app is better?  No app store approval via that route.  You just have to distribute it yourself rather than via the app store. Could even try something like Diawi, although those installations might expire after 30 days if I remember correctly.

Comment: I would suggest using a custom B2B app. You can simply distribute redemption codes to your contractors who can then install the app using the "redeem" function in the App Store.

Comment: Reminder to potential commenters: My question is not if option 1) 2) or 3) of the 6 provided by the very comprehensive linked answer are best. The question is if and how it's possible to make the first one - going through the App Store - work.

Comment: That is a question that cannot be answered here. Only Apple can say what they will and will not approve. They have been getting tougher on limited audience apps in recent times. Apps that may have been approved in the past could well be rejected today. There are reports of apps that have been in the apps store previously being rejected when an update is submitted. The B2B option is guaranteed to be accepted assuming the app is otherwise acceptable.  If you want to try option 1 then all you can do is submit and see what happens.

Comment: @Peter mind sharing whether you tried this, and how it went?

Comment: FWIW, the linked article has changed since the OP, and a similar section now reads: `4.2 Minimum Functionality - 
Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted.`. Interestingly, it doesn't specifically talk about audience or market size.

Comment: @jorisw To follow up: Due to the uncertainty and extra risk involved, the idea of an iOS App was dropped.