# How to install .ipa to other ios devices

Tags: ionic3, ipa

developed an ios app using ionic 3, (.ipa), now i want to give it to my users (this app is not public it's company's confidential, I don’t know how many users are going to install it and what will be devices and locations). How can i distribute it, like i can do with .appx and .apk I simply generated them and send anybody and they can use it. So how about .ipa (ios).

What are your valuable suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Private iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535693/private-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **over-the-air** feature provide by the apple. In [here](https://medium.com/@alexdimango/distributing-an-ipa-over-the-air-with-dropbox-ios-10-in-five-minutes-579fcdc7a0bb) you can find an example. **I haven't tried it.**

[image]