# Custom app (in-house) 'Ready for Sale' but not visible in app store

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, app-store, appstore-approval

I have published custom app (in-house - to be used by the employees of a particular organisation) on App Store under private distribution. I have also added my DUNS number and organisation Id.

Apple review team has approved the app within a day and it is now 'Ready for sale' but still not appearing on App Store. Reading many similar questions on stack overflow, I have check availability date, region & pricing (kept zero price), all are properly set, but still now appearing on App Store.

Finally I decided to ask new question regarding in-house apps.
Questions -
1) Will my app appear on App Store because it's a custom, private, in-house app?
2) If in case it does not appear on App Store, how can employees download and install this app on their iPhone? Because app is approved by Apple review team.

I tried to contact Apple, but no revert yet. I would appreciate some step-by-step process or any other links that can help me and employee find and install my iOS app on iPhone.

Comment: Once app is approved from Apple, it will take some time to appear on App Store in searches.

Comment: if its more that 48-hours, then you need to contact apple support team regarding this.

Comment: Yes, its now 60-hours. I have already sent email to apple, but no revert yet.
Any answers for my 2 questions?

Comment: then I would suggest you to call directly to apple support tam

Comment: Yes, I have sent them an email. 
Any answers for my 2 questions?

Comment: Is it a custom B2B app?  If so then you won't see it in the App Store, only in Apple Business Manager.

Comment: I have selected "Available for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager" this option under Pricing and Availability

Comment: Then you won't ever see that app in the App Store.  The specified organisations can purchase it via Apple Business Manager.

Comment: Thanks you all for your valuable answers.  I have changed it to appear on App Store. Now I can redirect to the app on App Store with link. However I cannot find app if I search on App Store directly. I think that because its a custom app and I have to market it via email with the link.

Answer (score 1):

Custom apps never appear on the App Store.

You need to specify the authorised organisation or Apple ID under *Available for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager* in App Store Connect.

The specified organisations can then purchase the app via Apple Business Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get some help on this stackoverflow's answer [Private iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535693/private-ios-app#targetText=The%20iOS%20Enterprise%20Distribution%20program,organization%20with%20a%20DUNS%20number.&targetText=The%20general%20public%20cannot%20see,app%2C%20purchase%20or%20install%20it).

Please check this point 2) iOS Developer Enterprise Program.
I have another detailed article on Enterprise program of Apple, please see this: https://www.computerworld.com/article/3249090/how-apple-developer-enterprise-license-works.html#targetText=Apple's%20Developer%20Enterprise%20Program%20lets,outside%20of%20the%20App%20Store.&targetText=Apple's%20Developer%20Enterprise%20Program%20lets%20enterprises%20develop%20and%20distribute%20proprietary,a%20private%20portal%20or%20URL.

I hope, this will help you.